# iBatis Batch Insert fails with socket write errors

Tags: java, jboss, ibatis

I am faced with a rather frustrating issue for the past couple of days. I am trying to improve performance by batching inserts using iBatis. However I see that the batch insert fails with one of the following errors
- java.sql.BatchUpdateException: IO Error: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
- java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-12161: TNS:internal error: partial data received
- java.sql.BatchUpdateException: IO Error: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

The details of the setup is as follows
- Application server is Jboss 5.0.1
- iBatis 2.3.4.732.1
- Spring 2.5.6

The batch insert code that I have is as follows

```
    try
    {
        final String finalStatement = statementName;
        int size = parameterList.size();
        int batchSize = 100;

        for(int ii=0; ii < size;)
        {
            int toIndex = ((ii + batchSize) > size ? size : (ii+batchSize));

            final List<Object> subList = parameterList.subList(ii, toIndex);
            ii += batchSize;
            count = getSqlMapClientTemplate().execute(new SqlMapClientCallback() 
            {
                public Object doInSqlMapClient(SqlMapExecutor executor) throws SQLException 
                {
                    executor.startBatch();
                    for(Object finalParameterObject : subList)
                    {                   
                        executor.insert(finalStatement, finalParameterObject);
                    }
                    Integer retCount = new Integer(executor.executeBatch());
                    return retCount;
                }
            });                       
        }
```

This works occasionally and at other times fails with one of the above errors.
We are using a connection pool and I have ensured that the blocking-timeout-millis is sufficiently high although I do not believe that this value is causing a problem here.
I have disabled the firewall, and still see the same issue.
It appears to me that the connection is being terminated by the database, I went thru the alert log (we are using oracle) but do not see any error on that log file. Looks like this is a configuration issue but I am not sure what needs to be changed as I have tried everything that I could think of.
Is there any thing that I am missing?

EDIT - If I make the batch size to be 10 in the above code (batchSize=10) then the batch insert works fine.

Answer (score 0):

not able to comment, the answer is based on some assumptions:

Are you using ibatis 2.3 or 3.x? If it is 2.3, are you setting jdbcType as NUMERIC but backing java field is Double/double? Or similar mismatch between actual java type and jdbc type in ibatis mapping?

I had a similar batch socket deadlock issue with ibatis 2.3, spring-orm and postgresql. After turning on debug logging of Postgresql JDBC driver, find lots of parse messages for one batch which supposes to be one. And it turned out that ibatis is setting different jdbc type for null value/ not null value on same column. The root cause was the ibatis mapping had one parameter's jdbcType as numeric but corresponding java type is Double.

Steps through ibatis's ParameterMap#setParameter(PreparedStatement, ParameterMapping, Object[], int), you will find out when the value is null, ibatis will setNull with jdbcType read from your mapping. When the value is not null, it will use typeHandler to set value. And the typeHandler, if no custom type handler provided, is determined by TypeHandlerFactory#getTypeHandler(Class type, String jdbcType). It is driven by the java type not jdbcType.